# add and delete virtual IP Linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, ip

I tried to figure out how to add and delete virtual ip in the same way I do with "ip addr add @ip dev @interface" and "ip addr del @ip dev @interface".

I succeed in changing the ip thanks to this code :

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    const char * name = "eth1";
    int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    struct sockaddr_in* addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr.ifr_addr;

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);

    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "1.1.1.1", &addr->sin_addr);

    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.0", &addr->sin_addr);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFNETMASK, &ifr);

    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr);
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
    ifr.ifr_flags |= (IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING);

    ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr);

    return 0;
}
```

But I didn't manage to add virual ip. Does any one know how it works ?

Thanks

Comment: Hae you considered looking at the errors you get back?

Comment: There's no error with my code, it changes the interface's IP but I want to know how to add an IP on an interface in the same way "ip addr add ..." does.